# How to load side by side same name DLLs (Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dll, sxs

I have a question about `side-by-side assemblies`.

Here's the situation:

I have an executable, `app.exe`, which loads plugins by searching a `plugins` directory. `app.exe` depends on a certain `A.dll`.

I'm developing a plugin which depends on an older, customized version of `A.dll` that has the same name. Updating this older, customized version to the newer version is impossible, so I thought I might be able to load the two `A.dll` files simultaneously.

Here's the directory structure:

```
\bin
    app.exe
    A.dll (newer version)
    \plugins
        myplugin.dll
```

Both versions of `A.dll` themselves depend on a huge number of other DLLs, which could have similar version problems. (I should also mention I'm working with a 64-bit application, if that makes a difference.)

How do I set this up in Visual Studio such that I can load both `A.dll` libraries at the same time, so that `myplugin.dll` uses the older version, whereas `app.exe` uses the newer version?

Answer (score 0):

Since these are plugins, you load them by calling `LoadLibrary`, or similar. In which case you can simply pass the full path to the DLL in order to load it.

Comment: Does the fact that `A.dll` has many other dependencies matter? In reality, it's more like `myplugin.dll` calls on `dep.dll`, which calls on `bin\A.dll`. I want `dep.dll` to call `bin\plugins\A.dll` instead (but can't modify `dep.cpp`). If I try `LoadLibrary` in `myplugin.cpp`, I get a "First chance exception" (Entry Point Not Found) error. What do I do in this case?

Comment: None of that detail is in the question